MS Project: How to auto-level tasks across multiple resources
I have a project that requires a large team of personnel, with multiples of each role (e.g. 3x quality engineers, 4x manufacturing engineers, 10x operators etc). The roles are fully generic and interchangeable within their discipline, i.e. imagine a team clones.
Due to the large size of the project, I've just assigned 1x of the relevant role to each task, e.g. Task A needs QE, Task B needs ME, Task C needs OPS and QE. I've then copied each resource to make multiple QE's, ME's etc., which are all clones of each other.
How do I make MS Project utilise these 'clone' resources when auto-leveling? Currently, Project just auto-levels the resource that was originally assigned, blowing the timeline out, and leaves the clones un-assigned. I was hoping since I just copy-pasted to create multiple resources, Project would see them as the same, but it doesn't seem to.

Instead of copying the resources, change the quantity by setting Max Units. For example, have one "Quality Engineer" resource with Max units = 3.
